# VBA - trying to create XML based on multiple ranges

Tags: excel, select, vba

I am trying to create an output as a XML (save as text file + ".xml"). 
The layout of the XML is:

```
<file-info> (forsendelse)
<record-info>
..account#..
</record-info>
</file-info>
```

I have created a range of fields where the XML is written so that I can just "copy" from the spreadsheet into the text file.

I have tried the following:

```
With Worksheets("XML_generator")
    Set forsendelse1 = .Range("G10:G31")
    dat = forsendelse1.Value
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set myrange1 = .Range("G32:G40")
    dat = myrange1.Value
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set myrange_acc = .Range("G41:G41")
    dat = myrange_acc.Value
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set myrange2 = .Range("G42:G73")
    dat = myrange2.Value
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set forsendelse2 = .Range("G74:G75")
    dat = forsendelse2.Value
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set a = fs.CreateTextFile(FPath & "Request_" & FName & "_" & FDate & ".xml", True)
End With
```

When I do this I only get the last range ("forsendelse2") in my XML. Does anyone have an idea on how to get this to work?

Please note:

- "..account#.." is just one cell in the workbook. This is the main
  data to change between exports.
- Not using the built in XML generator, since I require blank tags to be exported as well due to validation
- Splitting into 5 is so that I going forward can add more than one "record1 + ..account#.. + record2"

In the future I wish the result to look something like this:

```
<file-info> (forsendelse)
<record-info>
..account#.. (i.e "A2" from sheet)
</record-info>
<record-info>
..account#.. (i.e "A3" from sheet)
</record-info>
</file-info>
```

But since I haven't tried to do the "while loop" on this yet, firstly I hope someone can help me fix my Range issue :)

Thank you for taking your time!

Best regards
Andreas Petersen

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build up a string from multiple parts then you need to append each part, like this:

```
dat = "stack"
dat = dat & "overflow"
dat = dat & ".com"
```

The value of dat will now be "stackoverflow.com".

Your code is overwriting the existing value rather than appending to it:

```
dat = "stack"
dat = "overflow"
dat = ".com"
```

The value of dat will now be ".com"

Other issues:

- it's not clear why you are creating multiple FileSystemObjects that don't get used (only the last one gets used for anything)
- it may be easier to use MSXML2 and build a DOMDocument rather than trying to create the XML as a string